# Closed balls in metric space with trivial metric

Tags: metric-spaces

The problem is this: let two balls closed be in the metric space $(\Bbb{R},d)$ with the trivial metric, show that if the two balls intersect, then one is included in the other.
I conclude that both balls are equal, and therefore one is included in the other, but I'm not sure how to show it.

Comment: What is a trivial metric? And is $IR$ a notation for irrationals?

Comment: I think $IR $ stands for $\Bbb R$

Answer (score 2):

In the trivial metric, the ball $B_r (x) $ of radius $r $ centered at $x $ is  $$B_r (x)=\begin{cases}\{x\},&\ r <1\\ \ \\ \mathbb R,&\ r\geq1\end {cases} $$ If you now consider the nonempty  intersection $B_r (x) $ and $B_s (y) $:  either at least one of them is $\mathbb R $, in which case the inclusion is obvious, or they are $\{x\}$ and $\{y\}$, so equal.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Show there are two types of balls, the space itself and sets containing exactly one element.